# I want to send pictures and messages to users phone numbers without making them install the app. I am using firebase for storage ( swift iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, message

currently twilio.com offers a service where you can send messages and pictures through a phone number, I want to know is there any API or service that I can use to send my stored user data to their cell phone without making them install the app, I am not trying to Create a separate admin feature.

I don't want to create an admin feature,I want to see if I can send data to user phone-number without making them install the app.

Comment: does any body know if clouds offer that service?

Comment: that's obvious? isn't it

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to send push notifications to a phone that doesn't have your application installed. That would be way to much of a spamming machine. Essentially by installing your app, the user is taking the first step to opting in to your push notifications.

If you don't want to develop a native app, but are willing to send your user to a web page you create, you can consider implementing [web-based push notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client). In that case you're using a web app, instead of a native app.

The only way to send messages to a phone without an app installed is through SMS/MMS.

Comment: Thanks frank, do you know if I can retrieve stored Firebase data and send it as sms and mms to a phone number?

Comment: Just curious @Frank

Comment: Sending data from a database in an SMS sounds technically possible. Where you can do it, is something only you can find out by trying. The multi-step process is: 1) find out how to read data from the database, 2) find out how to send an SMS, 3) combine 1 and 2 into the use-case you're looking for.

Comment: Good feedback.  Thanks